# What is the best FREE VNC client and server compatible with Windows 7 and 2008 Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, vnc

I would like know if anybody can help me choosing a good VNC Software for Servers on Windows 2008 and Clients on Windows 7 (for now on Vista, but in October, all the machines will migrate to Windows 7)? Internet cannot help me finding.
And it's important that it's free, or not too expensive.
Thank you.

Comment: -1: You'd have to put absolutely no effort for uberweb to not tell you about remoting software. I would love to throw a link at you, but I think the spirit of this forum requires you to put effort first before asking off other people.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Comment: This seems to me a perfectly valid question...<br>
The user is asking for bet/better experiences with this type of tool...
It is a tool generally used for administration/networking...<br>
Users/Admins like me are very interested in feedbacks/experiences from other user... pointing the STRENGTHS and the WEAKNESS of the tools...<br>
If possible sharing some hacks for problems they solved...
Stay safe!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say try [**RealVNC**](http://www.realvnc.com/). It's good and very compatible. I'm using it on a Windows 7 Beta Edition, and it works without problems. For Windows 2008 Server, I don't know, but the kernel is the same as Vista.

Comment: I will try it and keep it updated.

Comment: I was going to suggest RealVNC, but they list Vista/2008 support as Personal Edition and not free edition). Maybe it's just bullcrap and free version works on any OS?

Comment: The free version works fine under Vista Business and Ultimate, in my experience at least.

Answer (score 7):

I can't find any good reason not to use built-in RDP server, as on Windows it beats VNC hands down. 3 sessions ought to be enough.

http://www.uvnc.com/ if you must.

Comment: A good reason is that Windows 7 Home Premium does not support Remote Desktop as a server.

Comment: Another good reason to use VNC instead of RDP is if you need to remote control a Win 2000 box.  We have to support this old Windows 2000 professional machine for one more month until new hardware/software is deployed and RDP is NOT an option on Windows 2000.  Though it pains me greatly to have to touch Windows 2000, VNC is the only way to go!

Answer (score 6):

I like [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/).

Comment: I have used UltraVNC with the Windows 7 RC.

Answer (score 6):

Tight VNC works best with Windows Vista/XP/2K3/2K8/7, either 32bit or 64bit.  We use it with our Customer sites, over 8,000 machines.  Issue with RealVNC/UVNC with  XP to 2008, works ok, but from 2008 to XP, Vista, 7 doesn't work too well.  Disconnects out of the blue.

We find TightVNC to be a good all-rounder, remote video is a little slower compared to RealVNC Winxp - Winxp or Win2K3 but it's reliable.

Comment: Tight VNC (also tried RealVNC and UltraVNC) is the fastest on Windows 7/Windows 2008 server and Ubuntu  which is the stack I have at home. RDP/terminal server is a better solution for a pure Windows environment. If you want cross platform support VNC is a reasonable option.

Comment: TigerVNC should be used instead.  It's originates from TightVNC and it is more up to date.  Has better security and a modern look, etc.

Answer (score 2):

TightVNC and TigerVNC.

Answer (score 1):

I know its not specifically what you are looking for, but you might want to give LogMeIn (http://www.logmein.com) a look. They offer a free version (paid adds support for file transfer, and printer/audio redirection) that I find works much better than VNC.

It requires no firewall setup on your part (Windows or hardware), and uses a central negotiation server so it makes it dead-simple to support users that have dynamic IPs (home users, laptop usrs, other varieties of telecommuters).

I have entire offices using it, it makes remote support a snap.

Comment: I use LogMeIn for private matters, and I find it's a great solution, and it's MAC, Windows and Linux compatible (web interface!).

Comment: I understand the need of pointing other 'ways' for newbies... 
But the question ask specifically for a VNC tool
Best place to put this info if you must in the question as a comment...

Answer (score 1):

TightVNC 2.0 does the job well on Win7.

Answer (score 1):

I know that [OnlineVNC Server](http://www.onlinevnc.com/download/online-vnc-server.html) has good Windows 7/Vista support. Maybe it will be usefull for you too. It works as Windows service and you can Login/LogOff/Lock current user without disconnecting.

Answer (score 0):

We have hundreds of mobile computers we maintain over Ultra VNC which proved itself to be the best one out there. TightVNC was giving us issue where a windows would be maximized on the desktop but I would not see it via tightVNC. Solved that issue by checking Poll Full Screen, System HookDll and Video Hook Driver option under the property page.
Hope this helps.